# JS Events that don't bubble (progress, loadedmetadata, etc)

Tags: javascript, events, event-bubbling

I found out that certain events on the video/audio tag don't bubble (loadedmetadata, progress, etc). Is this against the standard or is it common for other events?

How am I supposed to know what events are supposed to bubble or not bubble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can test it...
2. `readonly attribute boolean  bubbles;` check this property of the event.

**bubbles of type boolean, readonly**

> Used to indicate whether or not an event is a bubbling event. If the event can bubble the value is true, else the value is false.

[w3 source](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-interface) not w3School... :)

Comment: The event has to fire before you can get this information correct?

Comment: @JavascriptNewbie. Yes, that's correct. I missed the third option, **google each event**

Answer (score 1):

Bubbling events are usually those that need to bubble. Like if you click an element, you are also clicking its parents so it must bubble. But when a progress happens on a media element, it doesn't really happen on its parents the way keyup, click, mouseover etc do.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the specs. gdoron already posted a link to them and explained the each `Event` has an attribute indicating whether it bubbles or not - only useful when you have the event already.

Yet, look further down in that spec: In the [Event module definitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings) there is an overview of events and whether they bubble or not. Also, you will finde more events in the [DOM-Level3-Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/).

Also, you asked progress events. They are only a draft, but in the [section about proposed events](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/#suggested-names-for-events-using-the-progressevent-interface) you can find that they are not supposed to bubble.